# Property Problems

Tags: properties, synthesize

I am new to objective C And i was programing on C++ 
and now i dont know how to use @property ... 
and when to use it 
i red a lot about that and i didnt understand

and now i am trying to make a project a made it in C++ and trying to type in objective C way

i am trying To make (CHECKERS GAME) 
and there are 2 classes 
1- Board 
2- Cell 
... this is the Cell Class.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Cell : NSObject

{
    int number;
    char checker;
}
@end
```

And in board Class.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Cell.h"
//I dont know use it or not :S the @class
//@class Cell;

@interface Board : Cell
{
  //is the definition right ?
  Cell *DrawCell[64];

}
```

and when i type in board.m

```
   [ DrawCell [i] checker] = 'X' ;
```

it gives this error :
assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed

although i typed

```
@property (nonatomic) int number ;
@property (nonatomic) char checker;
```

and i tried to synthesize them 
but it also shows this error

please explain what to do and why to do and when to do

thanks :-)

Comment: You must use setters and getters. Right now you tried to use your getter to return the field, but it didn't return the field, it returned the value, and then you tried to assign a value to an anonymous return value.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use:

```m
[DrawCell [i] setChecker:'X']
```

or

```m
DrawCell[i].checker = 'X'
```

invoking as you did is the same as doing

```cpp
DrawCell[i].GetChecker() = 'X'
```

in C++, with this definition

```cpp
class Cell {
  public:
    char GetChecker() { return _checker; }
    void SetChecker(char newVal) { _checker = newVal; }
  private:
    char _checker;
}
```